# ImageView Keep On The Screen

Tags: android, imageview, screen

I have an image of how the application is running in the background can keep always on top

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using window type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT .
Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) .
This too can help-[FloatingView](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView)